# Legacy bootable usb with win10 - linux mint

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, mbr, grub-legacy

I have ssd and hdd. Both use mbr scheme. On my ssd I have mint and it is running well. I want to dual boot and install win10 on hdd but I have problem creating legacy bootable usb with win10 using linux mint to create. I have win10 iso and created bootable usb in legacy mode but when I select to boot from "usb drive" ( not uefi:usb drive) have an error "boot disc not found please insert bootable disc..." and wont start with installation however uefi mode boot fine from usb but because of mbr scheme cant install win10 on hdd. I dont want to change mbr to gpt. I want to stay on mbr. Can you please tell me how to create legacy bootable usb with win10 iso. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) – *A Linux program to create a Windows USB stick installer from a real Windows DVD or image*

Installation from the [Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install woeusb
```

You can then start the gui `woeusbgui` or use the commandline tool.

Example:

```
woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device /path/to/win10.iso /dev/sdX
```

where `/dev/sdX` is your USB device (e.g. `/dev/sdc`).